# Error: Couldn't find preset "latest" relative to directory "/app"

Tags: babeljs, deis, babel-loader, helmet.js

Receiving an error within my Deis app; with the introduction of [Helmet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/helmet) to the [frontend middleware](https://pastebin.com/BzTd7wA3). The app is initially based on [React Boilerplate](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/blob/master/internals/webpack/webpack.prod.babel.js) and most of the suggestions I've run by, I've already implemented/explored within the source and am still producing this "phantom" error.

This *only* occurs on the Deis app instance; when reproducing the steps locally, there's zero issues with it completing the (production) build process.

Sure, I *could* remove `helmet` from the middleware, but, I'd rather not...

**Error Output:**

```
> pkg-name@0.0.1 start /app
> npm run start:production

> pkg-name@0.0.1 start:production /app
> npm run build && npm run start:prod

> pkg-name@0.0.1 build /app
> cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config internals/webpack/webpack.prod.babel.js --color -p --progress

/app/node_modules/babel-register/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:328
        throw e;
        ^
2017-10-27T15:50:48+00:00 deis-app-name[]:
Error: Couldn't find preset "latest" relative to directory "/app"
    at /app/node_modules/babel-register/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:293:19
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at OptionManager.resolvePresets (/app/node_modules/babel-register/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:275:20)
    at OptionManager.mergePresets (/app/node_modules/babel-register/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:264:10)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (/app/node_modules/babel-register/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:249:14)
    at OptionManager.init (/app/node_modules/babel-register/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:368:12)
    at compile (/app/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:103:45)
    at loader (/app/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:14)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/app/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:531:32)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! pkg-name@0.0.1 build: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config internals/webpack/webpack.prod.babel.js --color -p --progress`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the pkg-name@0.0.1 build script.
```

**Dependency object value/pair:**

```
"dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "6.18.0",
    "babel-core": "6.21.0",
    "babel-eslint": "7.1.1",
    "babel-loader": "6.2.10",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "1.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-react-intl": "2.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-react-transform": "2.0.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-constant-elements": "6.9.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-inline-elements": "6.8.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "0.2.11",
    "babel-preset-latest": "6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-react-hmre": "1.1.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "6.16.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "6.20.0",
    "basic-auth": "^2.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-beta",
    "chalk": "^1.1.3",
    "cheerio": "0.22.0",
    "circular-dependency-plugin": "2.0.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "compression": "1.6.2",
    "cross-env": "3.1.3",
    "css-loader": "0.26.1",
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
    "dotenv-safe": "^4.0.4",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^1.5.4",
    "eslint-import-resolver-webpack": "0.8.0",
    "exports-loader": "0.6.3",
    "express": "4.14.0",
    "express-basic-auth": "^1.1.2",
    "file-loader": "0.9.0",
    "fontfaceobserver": "^2.0.13",
    "helmet": "^3.9.0",
    "html-loader": "0.4.4",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.24.1",
    "image-webpack-loader": "2.0.0",
    "immutable": "3.8.1",
    "imports-loader": "0.6.5",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "invariant": "2.2.2",
    "ip": "1.1.4",
    "lodash": "4.17.2",
    "minimist": "1.2.0",
    "moment": "2.18.0",
    "ngrok": "2.2.4",
    "nsp": "^2.8.1",
    "offline-plugin": "4.5.2",
    "query-string": "^5.0.1",
    "react": "15.4.1",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "15.4.1",
    "react-dom": "15.4.1",
    "react-helmet": "3.2.2",
    "react-intl": "2.1.5",
    "react-paginate": "^4.4.4",
    "react-redux": "4.4.6",
    "react-router": "3.0.0",
    "react-router-redux": "4.0.6",
    "react-router-scroll": "0.4.1",
    "react-scroll": "^1.5.5",
    "react-widgets": "^4.0.2",
    "react-widgets-moment": "^4.0.2",
    "reactstrap": "^5.0.0-alpha.3",
    "redux": "3.6.0",
    "redux-form": "^7.0.4",
    "redux-immutable": "3.0.8",
    "redux-saga": "0.14.0",
    "redux-saga-routines": "^2.0.2",
    "reselect": "2.5.4",
    "rimraf": "2.5.4",
    "sanitize.css": "4.1.0",
    "snyk": "^1.45.0",
    "style-loader": "0.13.1",
    "styled-components": "1.1.2",
    "svg-sprite-loader": "^3.4.0",
    "url-loader": "0.5.7",
    "warning": "3.0.0",
    "webpack": "2.2.0-rc.3",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "1.9.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.15.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "2.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "coveralls": "2.11.15",
    "enzyme": "2.6.0",
    "eslint": "3.11.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "13.0.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "10.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "2.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "6.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-redux-saga": "0.1.5",
    "eventsource-polyfill": "0.9.6",
    "jest-cli": "18.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "3.2.1",
    "node-plop": "0.5.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "null-loader": "0.1.1",
    "plop": "1.7.3",
    "pre-commit": "1.1.3",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.5",
    "sinon": "2.0.0-pre"
  }
```

**Runtime configuration:**

- webpack: 2.2.0-rc.3
- babel core: 6.26.0
- babel loader: 6.18.0
- helmet: 3.9.0

**Environment workflow:**

- Running on a Deis instance (kube & docker)

**Environment variables:**

```
NODE_ENV                   production
NODE_MODULES_CACHE         false
NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION      true
```

**Additional resources:**

- https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/6558
- https://github.com/babel/babel-loader#usage
- https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/pull/1236#issuecomment-305821664
- [BabelJs over Heroku: Couldn't find preset "env" relative to directory "/app"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46963058/babeljs-over-heroku-couldnt-find-preset-env-relative-to-directory-app)
- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#devdependencies

Comment: Sounds like probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46963058/babeljs-over-heroku-couldnt-find-preset-env-relative-to-directory-app?

Comment: Thanks for the response – I've updated the dependency lists to reflect babel entirely being outside of the devDependencies, also set the environment variable `NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false`. None of those appear to have resolved the error being experienced. Any other advice?

Comment: When I remove the `.helmet()` (L11) referenced above in the frontendMiddleware.js link, it passed the reported error. I'm struggling to understand why helmet is causing babel fail, on my production environment? Is this a configuration issue?

Comment: For what it's worth, I maintain Helmet and this doesn't look related to Helmet specifically.

Comment: @EvanHahn – indeed you may be correct, however, when removed from the middleware, it, somehow, work... I've reached out to the babel slack channel, I'll follow up here in the event I hear more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I do - in development (on your local machine), I just install all the latest babel deps in a grandparent directory. Node.js will walk up the filesystem looking for its dependencies (node_modules). This way you don't have to install Babel for each project. This technique doesn't even need `NODE_PATH` or `npm link`, it just works like this:

```
$HOME/
  projects/
    node_modules/  # install all babel deps here
    project-a/
    project-b/
    project-c/
```

or, even simpler, you can just install babel deps in `$HOME/node_modules`, and that will work too. Just an idea. This is just the way Node.js works - it walks up the filesystem all the way to $HOME, looking for node_modules/x, if it can't find it in $HOME/node_modules/x, then it fails.

Comment: This is ridiculous, but it works.  I've been fighting with this for _way_ too long.  Thanks for a workaround.

Comment: You sir need a reward.

Comment: what happens sometimes is that I cd to $HOME, and forget where I am, and run an `npm install` command, so I end up getting node_modules there anyway

Comment: @reergymerej this is actually simply the way node_modules resolution works, it has to do with Node.js works...it just walks up the filesystem towards `/` until it finds the first matching dependency

Answer (score 0):

I removed "latest" from presest array and the "prestes" equals ["react","stage-0"]